Jetpack Compose infinite scroll. derivedStateOf only recomposing on the first load
I'm creating an infinite scroll in Jetpack Compose. Given the LazyRow:
LazyRow(
    contentPadding = PaddingValues(start = 10.dp, end = 10.dp, bottom = 10.dp),
    horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(10.dp),
) {
    items (
        lastIndexToShow,
            key = { index ->
                games.getOrNull(index)?.id ?: index
            }
        ) { index ->
            Box {
                games.getOrNull(index)?.let { game ->
                    GameCard(game = game, index = index)
                } ?:
                Box(modifier = Modifier
                    .size(width = 400.dp, height = 350.dp)
                    .padding(0.dp))
            }

            LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
                fetchNewPageIfNeeded(section, index)
            }
        }
    }
}

games and lastIndexToShow come both from my ViewModel. The idea of lastIndexToShow is to allow showing empty spaces while loading in case of fast scrolling, so that the scroll never stops when hitting the end of games list before loading. And this is exactly the variable that ain't working fine.
Here's how I defined them:
games
private var _games = mutableStateMapOf<String, MutableList<Game>>()
val games: SnapshotStateMap<String, MutableList<Game>> = _games

lastIndexToShow
val lastIndexToShow: (String) -> State<Int> = { section ->
    derivedStateOf {
        maxOf(0, minOf((totalGamesGroupBy?.get(section) ?: 1) - 1, (_games[section] ?: emptyList()).size + threshold))
    }
}

then I pass lastIndexToShow like this.-
lastIndexToShow = { section ->
    val indexToShow by gameViewModel.lastIndexToShow(section)
    indexToShow 
}

If instead of this variable I just set 1000 for the last index to show (I'm fetching 30 elements pages) I can see the row showing the new elements smoothly, so I'm pretty sure the issue is with the definition of lastIndexToShow.

I don't really understand the calculation of lastIndexToShow, but why don't you just use something like this in your LazyRow: items(count = games.size + threshold, key = ...)

Thank you @Leviathan, the extra calculation is just to make sure that the index stays between 0 and the maximum number of elements I can get, but your simplification definitely works for testing purposes. Unfortunately, I'm getting the same results, I just see the 50 first items (the 30 corresponding to the loaded page + 20 corresponding to the threshold), as if count param isn't updated.

@ssantos Why is _games a var and not val

Thank you @AdnanHabib, I'm guessing I changed it during one of my tests, but still shouldn't make any difference, right?

Are you sure that updates to games in the ViewModel are being reflected in the UI?

Exactly, if I set any random large number instead of lastIndexToShow, I can see the new pages loaded.

The problem seems to lie here:
private val _games = mutableStateMapOf<String, MutableList<Game>>()

mutableStateMapOf creates a map that will be observed for changes to trigger a recomposition. That's a feature of the map only, though. Adding, removing or replacing items will trigger a recomposition, changes to the objects inside the map, however, will not be observed.
The values of the map are MutableLists. You can add elements to that lists, but that won't make any changes to the map: The map will still contain the same lists. only the contents of the lists have changed, not the lists themselves:
_games[section]?.addAll(data)

This will only read a value of the map. It then takes that value (a MutableList) and adds data to it. So the map keeps untouched: No new, removed or replaced values (i.e. a new or deleted MutableList), only the already existing MutableList was modified.
Since only structural changes to the map itself will be monitored by Compose, no recomposition will be triggered by the above.
That's the tricky thing about mutable objects in general (not just MutableLists), it is hard to keep track when they change. That's also one of the reasons why a common recommendation is to use immutable objects in such cases:
private val _games = mutableStateMapOf<String, List<Game>>()

The map is still an observable State, but now it only allows values of type List. That's the same as MutableList, except there are no methods to add, remove or replace an element: This list is immutable and cannot be changed anymore after it was created. Adding data would now be done like this instead:
_games[section] = _games[section]?.plus(data)

plus creates a new (immutable) list with the entries of _games[section] plus the entries of data. This new list will then be saved in the map. And that will, finally, be registered as a change to the map so a recomposition is scheduled.
At first glance it might seem inefficient to always create a new list. That's true to a certain degree, but in general this won't be noticeable since creating a list is pretty light-weight as long as you don't have millions of entries and repeat it in a loop. Instead you will gain other advantages like increased thread safety and better encapsulation preventing other kinds of bugs. As a general rule, try to use as much immutable data structures as possible.
One thing is still missing: The null-handling when the _games map doesn't have a value for the section key. In the original version the data was just skipped. I guess what you actually want is that a new entry is created instead:
_games[section] = (_games[section] ?: emptyList()) + data


Thank you @Leviathan, it's cristal clear. As for the last note, in my scenario I technically couldn't reach the addition point with an empty value in _games[section], but still a very good point :)

Finally, the problem was on the way I was updating the games map. I was adding new elements like this.-
_games[section]?.addAll(data)

BUT seems this wasn't considered an update in the map. Setting completely a new list like this.-
_games[section] = _games[section]?.plus(data) ?: listOf()

Did the trick.

To add an explanation: Only the map itself is an observable State. Any changes to the map (like setting _games[section]) will trigger a recomposition. _games[section]?.addAll(data), on the other hand, doesn't touch the map itself, it only changes the list inside the map (that still remains the same list!). Since that is just a simple MutableList and not an observable State changes to that list will not trigger a recomposition.

That's one of the reasons why it is common practice to only use immutable objects: Would the list have been of type List in from the start (instead of MutableList) you would never have run into this problem because there wouldn't even be an addAll function in the first place, only plus.

Thank you @Leviathan for the clarification. It kind of reminds to the way states work in React, I should have realized before. The funny thing is I started with an immutable list and switched to mutable in order to be able to update it :D Still, it's weird how the LazyRow was showing all the refreshed items as long as I set a static large items amount. Anyway, I'm happy to accept your explanation if you're up for including it as an answer :)
